# Why does $KMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$ evaluate to semicolon?

Tags: visual-studio, driver, inf, kmdf

**The Context**

This question is related to the [RAMDisk Storage Driver Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/storage/ramdisk), but also applies to the [Toaster Sample Driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/general/toaster/toastDrv), and may even apply to any driver that make use of .INX files and CoInstallers.

My original question was "Why am I missing the WdfCoInstallerXXXXX.dll file when my build was successful?" After reviewing the **ramdisk.inf** file, I realized that all the coinstaller sections are empty (replaced with a semicolon). This lead me to the question below.

**The Question**

The coinstaller section of the **ramdisk.inx** file make use of the *$KMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$* variable. This should be a valid variable according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545473(v=vs.85).aspx) page. However, upon successful build, all lines that reference the *$KMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$* variable evaluate to a semicolon in the generated **ramdisk.inf** file. Why?

**Additional Information**

All other variables in the **ramdisk.inx** files, such as *$KMDFVERSION$* and *$ARCH$*, gets evaluated properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Cause**

It turns out that the cause of this was the fact that I don't have the specified KMDF library version install, even though I recently installed the latest WDK 10. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-drivers/develop/driver_model_settings_properties_for_driver_projects) page, "if you omit the KMDF Version Minor, the most recent minor version is used."

In other words, I was trying to use KMDF version 1.15, when I only support 1.7, 1.9, and 1.11. You can check the redistributable directory to see which version you support. Mine is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\wdf\x64`.

**The Fix**

Go to `Project->Properties->Driver Settings->Driver Model`, and select the appropriate KMDF version. After that, rebuild, and your **.INF** file will be properly populated, and your driver package will contain the appropriate WdfCoInstallerXXXXX.dll.